# How to catch POST-request in SvelteKit+Vercel

Tags: deployment, vercel, sveltekit, production

I do not understand how to catch POST-request in production Vercel hosting.

Catching POST-request locally works fine.

### Log message in Vercel Dashboard:

Status Code | 403

Level |  warning
Type | Serverless Function